# Interpreting complex number in step size in NumPy RClass (`np.r_`)

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

Here is a piece of code:

```
np.concatenate(([3], [0]*5, np.arange(-1, 1.002, 2/9.0)))

# the above outputs 
array([ 3.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        , -1.        , -0.77777778, -0.55555556, -0.33333333,
       -0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.33333333,  0.55555556,  0.77777778,
        1.        ])
```

Although this is verbose, it's pretty understandable. And here's another way to get the same output using an (ab)used notation, with complex number as step size.

```
np.r_[3, [0]*5, -1:1:10j]

# the above outputs
array([ 3.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        , -1.        , -0.77777778, -0.55555556, -0.33333333,
       -0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.33333333,  0.55555556,  0.77777778,
        1.        ])
```

I'm trying to understand how the step size in the first approach is equivalent to the complex number step size (`10j`) in the second approach.

```
2/9.0  == 10j  # how?
```

I have read in [`scipy reference documentation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/basic.html) that `-1:1:10j` means we want to produce 10 values between `-1:1`, both sides inclusive. But, how does that `10j` translate to `0.2222`?

- Any intuitive ideas or explanations?
- Also, what are other useful NumPy examples that we can do with this sort of expression?

---

P.S. I have already looked at [range-builder-r-slice-with-complex-but-not-imaginary-step-magnitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940544/range-builder-r-slice-with-complex-but-not-imaginary-step-magnitude-is-u) but that doesn't offer much ideas.

Comment: With a complex step `r_` uses `np.linspace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `start`, `stop` (both included), and `size`, then `step` is calculated as follows:

```
step = (stop - start) / (size - 1)
```

With `start = -1`, `stop = 1`, `size = 2` you will get `step = 2` and array `[-1, 1]`

With `start = -1`, `stop = 1`, `size = 3` you will get `step = 1` and array `[-1, 0, 1]`

With `start = -1`, `stop = 1`, `size = 10` from the slice `-1:1:10j` you will get `step = 2/9` and array

```
[-1.        , -0.77777778, -0.55555556, -0.33333333, -0.11111111,
  0.11111111,  0.33333333,  0.55555556,  0.77777778,  1.        ]
```

**Note**: For a complex number such as `10j`, np.abs(10j) would be calculated first to get a real number.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of the `r_` docs is:

> However, if
>       `step` is an imaginary number (i.e. 100j) then its integer portion is
>       interpreted as a number-of-points desired and the start and stop are
>       inclusive. In other words `start:stop:stepj` is interpreted as
>       `np.linspace(start, stop, step, endpoint=1)` inside of the brackets.

This is a notational trick used in a couple of the **classes** in `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` (`mgrid` is another).  This isn't a general `numpy` or python trick.  The use of `class` definition (not function) and custom `__getitem__` method is key.

As for the numeric details, check the code for `np.linspace`.  (MATLAB has a function with the same name).

Maybe this comparison with `arange` will help give an intuitive feel.

```
In [65]: np.arange(-1,1.01,.2)                                                  
Out[65]: 
array([-1.00000000e+00, -8.00000000e-01, -6.00000000e-01, -4.00000000e-01,
       -2.00000000e-01, -2.22044605e-16,  2.00000000e-01,  4.00000000e-01,
        6.00000000e-01,  8.00000000e-01,  1.00000000e+00])
In [66]: _.shape                                                                
Out[66]: (11,)
In [67]: np.linspace(-1,1,11)                                                   
Out[67]: array([-1. , -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2,  0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])
```

The `arange` produced 11 values, so we had to use the same size number in `linspace`.  Note that `linspace` handling of the end point is nicer, resulting in a cleaner display of the float values (which are not exact in either case).

If we use 10 instead, the spacing is correct (.2222...*9=1.9999....).  To get 10 values we have to step 9 times. Or divide the range into 9 intervals.

```
In [68]: np.linspace(-1,1,10)                                                   
Out[68]: 
array([-1.        , -0.77777778, -0.55555556, -0.33333333, -0.11111111,
        0.11111111,  0.33333333,  0.55555556,  0.77777778,  1.        ])
```

`arange` with floats is messier than the equivalent starting with integers:

```
In [70]: np.arange(-10,11,2)/10                                                 
Out[70]: array([-1. , -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2,  0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])
```